# Can't install packages using apt-get install or Software Center

Tags: installation, updates, package-management, install-from-source

I installed recently in my personal computer 12.04.

When a try to install some software (Dropbox or Chromium per example) from the Ubuntu software Center or when I try to install some package using the terminal (`sudo apt-get install guake` for example), I find an issue. There is some problem with the packages list.

What I can do? I tried to run `sudo apt-get update`, but the issue persist.

Comment: Can you please let us know what the error message said?

Answer (score 4):

First make sure your Internet connection works. Then enter the following commands one by one, in terminal.

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
```

If that didn't work,

Go to

**Edit > Software Sources** in Software Center.

Set **"Main Server"** in **"Download From"** drop down menu.

Then run **sudo apt-get update** in terminal again.

Comment: Hmm, we could really use a 'aptgetsane' script to triage issues like this. We basically have no idea how many PPAs are installed or what state the packaging is in. It would be neat to revert to installation defaults, while saving all the original settings, to diagnose said issues.