# Unable to install VIM

Tags: 13.04, vim

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 and I assumed that vim comes by default. There is a /etc/vim on my system (assuming it refers to the same thing). However, I was unable to do a vim abc.txt. Instead, I got a reply stating that vim is not recognized. Please refer to the following and provide me a solution.

```
rahul@hpdv6:~/Downloads/VIM/vim64/src$ sudo apt-get install vim
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package vim is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'vim' has no installation candidate
rahul@hpdv6:~/Downloads/VIM/vim64/src$
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi belacqua, `apt-cache search ^vim` shows nothing.

Comment: I do, but the letters 'v', 'i' and 'm' are in red. Is that a concern ?

Comment: I get the following message - 
`rahul@hpdv6:/usr/bin$ /usr/bin/vim abc.txt
bash: /usr/bin/vim: Too many levels of symbolic links`

Comment: The command does not seem to recognize vim.

`rahul@hpdv6:/usr/bin$ sudo update-alternatives --config editor
There are 2 choices for the alternative editor (providing /usr/bin/editor).

  Selection    Path            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /bin/nano        40        auto mode
  1            /bin/ed         -100       manual mode
  2            /bin/nano        40        manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: `

Comment: I just did a `sudo apt-get install linux-doc` and that seems to work.

Comment: I'm moving my questions/comments to an answer, for now.  You should add your answers (additional output, etc..) to the question, by editing the original.

Comment: Since none of these suggestions answered the question, the answer is here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/301934/vim-is-not-working-fine-in-ubuntu-13-04

Answer (score 1):

Vim should be installed by default on all machines. As well, that command should work just fine. You may want to try these:

```
sudo apt-get install vim-tiny
```

for the command line mode or:

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

for the full GUI edition.

Comment: Hi llamositopia, I have tried all possible alternatives. It does not seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried using `sudo apt-get remove vim` followed by `sudo apt-get install vim` it may be a problem with the current installation not showing up.

Comment: I did that too. Infact, I believe I am having the same problem with the g++ package.

Answer (score 0):

You must not have the source enabled. This link will open it in the software center: http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/vim

If you need to enable the source it will give you a button

It shows up for me.

Comment: Hi GM-Script-Writer-62850, I understand that it should show up, but it doesn't.

Comment: can you post your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file? tried running `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: I get the following message when I run the former: 
`rahul@hpdv6:/usr/bin$ sudo /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo: /etc/apt/sources.list: command not found`

Comment: Yes, I tried running `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` it is not a script is a config file

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. The result is too long for this commend box to take. Should I post it as an answer to my question?

Comment: That or on http://pastebin.com

Comment: Here, http://pastebin.com/HHu8XCKc

Comment: @belacqua , please provide your insights too.

Comment: `sudo apt-get update;apt-get download vim` does that work?

Comment: Update seems to happening the way it should, but vim is still unrecognizable.

`Fetched 149 kB in 11s (13.4 B/s)                                                      
Reading package lists... Done
E: Can't select candidate version from package vim as it has no candidate

Comment: http://mirrors.us.kernel.org/ubuntu//pool/main/v/vim/vim_7.3.547-6ubuntu5_i386.deb can you install it manually? why are you using 32bit this day and age, pretty sure everything in the past decade is 64bit hardware

Answer (score 0):

What does `apt-cache search ^vim` show?

What happens if you run `/usr/bin/vim abc.txt` ?

I'm guessing you or someone did something odd with the system (installs or package removals, or file deletion).

Try 
`sudo update-alternatives --config editor`

If that doesn't work, are you able to install any other packages? E.g., `sudo apt-get install tidy` or anything else?

Try the steps in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/184982/8844/%22this%20link%22) .

Comment: I just tried `sudo apt-get install linux-doc`, and that worked fine. I think I have probably done something funny.

Comment: Yeah, I'm concerned that you might have gotten other things deleted or moved around.   You might post the contents of your /etc/apt/sources.list file to see if there's anything odd there.