# Vim is not working fine in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: software-recommendation, vim

How to install full version of Vim editor in ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 3):

The default vim package installed for Ubuntu is [vim-tiny [image: Install vim-tiny]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vim-tiny), I believe, which can be limited in its functionality. You should install the full package: [vim [image: Install vim]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vim)

If I remember correctly, this will also install [vim-runtime [image: Install vim-runtime]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vim-runtime) as well.

Comment: @Gerhard Burger Thanks. I never use USC and forget how to add links to directly install packages. :-/

Comment: You're welcome, it is very easy: you can use [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) and [this script on stackapps](http://stackapps.com/questions/2405/ask-ubuntu-toolbar-buttons-a-set-of-toolbar-buttons-for-ask-ubuntu-that-make-i)

Comment: You're correct, but even though the package "vim" is suggested, it's not available in apt-get for some reason. Instead if you install vim-runtime, you'll see that the vim package will also be installed.